# Can we use Bulma CSS for Android apps?

Tags: android, css, bulma, css-frameworks, android-app-indexing

Can we use Bulma CSS for Android apps?
I mean like we use in web apps can we also use CSS frameworks like Bulma for Android apps?

Comment: Android doesn't use HTML or CSS natively.  So no, unless your entire app is in a webview.

Comment: You technically could if you are building your app using React Native. This allows you to build a native app using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. You could use Bulma as the CSS Framework for your app.- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Answer (score 0):

Web development and mobile development are completely different.

On Android, there is [Flexbox Layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) that you could use for example or if you want more librairies have a look at this [awesome-android-ui](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui).